# Redis docker container not storing data in redis database

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have two containers for my `nodejs application` and `redis database`. I used `docker compose file` to create both containers with this command `docker-compose up -d --build`, the containers start, my redis connection gets established and I can see on the log that it gets connected and ready to be used.
On login, I wrote a logic that stores user `refresh token` and `user id` in `redis database`. This has been tested locally and works very well. No issues.
But when I create and run the app via docker container, nothing gets stored in `redis database` on user login. I don't even know where to begin to debung because it is not giving me any idea at all.
If I run same code locally outside the docker container, it runs fine.
Here is my docker file:

```
FROM  node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

COPY client/package*.json client/
RUN npm run install-client --only=production


COPY api/package*.json api/
RUN npm run install-api --only=production



COPY client/ client/
RUN npm run client-build --prefix client


COPY api/ api/



USER node

CMD [ "npm", "start", "--prefix", "api" ]



EXPOSE 5000
```

My compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  redisdb:
    container_name: redisdb
    hostname: redis
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"


  fullstack-cms:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    env_file:
      - ./api/.env
    depends_on:
      - redisdb
```

And it is not showing any error. When I used `console.log` and checked the value of the redis variable in my code, it showed `undefined`. Locally, everything works fine, just not working via docker container, kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

The redis images have persistence disabled by default. Full documentation available here: https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/

```
version: "3"
services:
  redisdb:
    container_name: redisdb
    hostname: redis
    image: redis
    command: redis-server
    volumes:
        - /host/path/to/your/redis/data:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"


  fullstack-cms:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    env_file:
      - ./api/.env
    depends_on:
      - redisdb
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. Please, how do I get the exact path to my redis data?

Comment: You chose where you want that data to live on your docker host.

Comment: how about the command flag? what does it do?

Comment: Thank you. I did as you recommended:  I added volumes:
      - cache:/data and declared the volumes like this at the end: volumes:
  cache:. Image got rebuilt and redis connected but still same issue. It is not storing anything

Comment: @ThatkingzThatkingz I think it has to be an absolute path. So it it has to start with a /

Comment: Thanks man, I added that but still same issue. Thanks for trying to help. I appreciate.